# How can I ensure the independent features in a dataset have maximum positive coefficients on running logistics regression

Tags: logistic, regression-coefficients, extrapolation

I have a sample dataset with about a million records with about 7 feature variables. On running logistic regression on this dataset, I got 5 features with a positive coefficient and 2 with a negative coefficient.

Now I need to extrapolate this data to about 50 times and add a couple of feature variables to the set. How can I ensure that after generating random data and adding more features, I achieve maximum features with positive coefficients?

Is there a way to identify patterns or relationships that I could use to define rules for replicating the data in the way that I want ?

If this sounds a bit vague, I'd be happy to have a detailed discussion on this if possible.

Comment: Yes can you add more information about the "extrapolation"?

Comment: By extrapolation I just meant replicating the data to a significant size keeping the features intact